# Where can I get some MuSig2 test vectors?

Tags: multi-signature, taproot, schnorr-signatures, musig

I am writing a MuSig2 library and need some test vectors. This should include the hash functions used.

Comment: I'll leave to a MuSig(2) expert to answer the question but I don't think these exist yet. The MuSig(2) authors haven't included it in a secp256k1 release and it has been described as "super-experimental" https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/issues/997. Some people are using it on mainnet though https://twitter.com/MuunWallet/status/1459769042072440833?s=20

Comment: At the moment, your best bet is the the MuSig2 PR to secp256k1-zkp: https://github.com/ElementsProject/secp256k1-zkp/pull/131. It doesn't update the musig-spec.mediawiki yet and is only code so far. Still happy to hear your feedback there on the API design etc.

Comment: @MichaelFolkson In the linked secp256k1 issue #997, I didn't mean to say that it's super-experimental. I really meant the opposite and "Is musig2 "super-experimental" [...]?" was a rhetorical question: I assume that the other contributors don't think it's super-experimental. I personally feel very confident in the scheme. It has a security proof, and the core ideas have been verified by others independently (e.g., FROST)
The only thing that I think is experimental is the implementation, which is currently PR'd to secp256k1-zkp but maybe should be PR'd to secp256k1 as an experimental module.

Comment: @real-or-random: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not even a published specification for MuSig2. One is being worked on at https://github.com/jonasnick/bips/blob/musig2/bip-musig2.mediawiki, but it is incomplete.

There are some test vectors [here](https://github.com/ElementsProject/secp256k1-zkp/blob/master/src/modules/musig/tests_impl.h).